# Boost Log : File Rotation

Tags: c++, boost, boost-log

I have a doubt about Boost log file rotation. The log file rotation happens based on time and file size.

**rotation_size = 30 * 1024 * 1024**

**time_based_rotation = sinks::file::rotation_at_time_point(0, 0, 0)**

When the file reaches mentioned file size, another file will be created.Assume the file get rotated before the mentioned time point.My doubt is the file will get rotate on mentioned time point or not.

I have an issue :

File for x1/mm/yy_N1 created and reaches file size, next file rotation happened(x1/mm/yy_N2). The new file is not created for x2/mm/yy_N3 at time point(0,0,0), so the logs for x2 got written in x1/mm/yy_N2.
I want to get rotation on both condition(size as well as time point). Help me out.

Answer (score 3):

As stated in the [docs](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_71_0/libs/log/doc/html/log/detailed/sink_backends.html#log.detailed.sink_backends.text_file.file_rotation), file rotation will happen when either one or both criteria are satisfied and the library attempts to write a log record. Therefore, if your log file reaches 30 MiB before midnight, it will get rotated at that point, and then again at midnight (or past midnight, as soon as a log record is written) regardless of the file size.

Comment: What will be the reason for day2 logs are written in day1 log file.

Comment: I don't know, you'll have to provide more information, like a reproducer code sample, for example, or debug yourself. As a possible point of investigation, maybe it has something to do with appending to the previous log file upon restarting your process.

Answer (score 2):

Log will rotate at both occurrence. Check [code](https://github.com/boostorg/log/blob/e903d3aef7be37adb877655b9ac39d4a954ca943/src/text_file_backend.cpp#L1364) here.

For other proof consider below code.

```
#include <boost/log/trivial.hpp>
#include <boost/log/common.hpp>
#include <boost/log/keywords/file_name.hpp>
#include <boost/log/keywords/format.hpp>
#include <boost/log/utility/setup.hpp>

#include <thread>

namespace logging = boost::log;
namespace sinks = boost::log::sinks;
namespace src = boost::log::sources;
namespace expr = boost::log::expressions;
namespace attrs = boost::log::attributes;
namespace keywords = boost::log::keywords;

void init()
{
    logging::add_file_log
    (
        keywords::file_name = "sample_%N.log",                                        
        keywords::rotation_size = 256 * 1024,
        keywords::time_based_rotation = sinks::file::rotation_at_time_interval(boost::posix_time::seconds(30)), 
        keywords::format = "[%TimeStamp%]: %Message%"                                 
    );

    logging::core::get()->set_filter
    (
        logging::trivial::severity >= logging::trivial::info
    );
}

int main(int, char*[])
{
    init();

    while(1) {
    BOOST_LOG_TRIVIAL(trace) << "A trace severity message";
    BOOST_LOG_TRIVIAL(debug) << "A debug severity message";
    BOOST_LOG_TRIVIAL(info) << "An informational severity message";
    BOOST_LOG_TRIVIAL(warning) << "A warning severity message";
    BOOST_LOG_TRIVIAL(error) << "An error severity message";
    BOOST_LOG_TRIVIAL(fatal) << "A fatal severity message";
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(10));
}

    return 0;
}
```

Now see to listing of log files with timestamp.

> ```
> -rw-r--r-- 1 manthan manthan 256K 2019-11-28 12:52:01.451001000 +0530 sample_12.log
> -rw-r--r-- 1 manthan manthan  58K 2019-11-28 12:51:35.003001000 +0530 sample_11.log
> -rw-r--r-- 1 manthan manthan 256K 2019-11-28 12:51:29.363001000 +0530 sample_10.log
> -rw-r--r-- 1 manthan manthan  49K 2019-11-28 12:51:05.011001000 +0530 sample_9.log
> -rw-r--r-- 1 manthan manthan 256K 2019-11-28 12:51:00.563001000 +0530 sample_8.log
> -rw-r--r-- 1 manthan manthan 248K 2019-11-28 12:50:35.007001000 +0530 sample_7.log
> -rw-r--r-- 1 manthan manthan 5.0K 2019-11-28 12:50:05.003001000 +0530 sample_6.log
> -rw-r--r-- 1 manthan manthan 256K 2019-11-28 12:50:04.347001000 +0530 sample_5.log
> -rw-r--r-- 1 manthan manthan  36K 2019-11-28 12:49:35.007001000 +0530 sample_4.log
> -rw-r--r-- 1 manthan manthan 256K 2019-11-28 12:49:31.211001000 +0530 sample_3.log
> -rw-r--r-- 1 manthan manthan 244K 2019-11-28 12:49:05.003001000 +0530 sample_2.log
> -rw-r--r-- 1 manthan manthan  19K 2019-11-28 12:48:35.003001000 +0530 sample_1.log
> -rw-r--r-- 1 manthan manthan 256K 2019-11-28 12:48:32.875001000 +0530 sample_0.log
> ```

From above files' timestamp it is clear that file rotation happens at both events.

Comment: Thanks for the info and your effort. I want to know , what will be the reason for the issue which I was mentioned in the question..can you help me out

Comment: You should try with small size and small interval to reproduce issue. Your current setting seems too large to for someone to reproduce.

Comment: You can also try setting file size too large and time near in future, to check that whether it is logrotate at given time or not.

Comment: And also make sure your test program is writing something to log continuously for testing.

Comment: I have tried with the cases you mentioned(works fine). Application runs in a multi threaded environment(issue occurs rarely), is there any actions should be taken on synchronous part.

Comment: I don't think so. Is there any possibility at specified time your application may not be running OR it is get crashed?

Comment: Yes, application was crashed.

Comment: Then, that's issue. When application is not running then how can it rotate log file. So this is not issue related to boost.log